# How to differentiate name of columns in different tables?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, their structure looks like this:

```
table 1: id, name, description

table 2: id, otherDescription
```

I want to set the value of "description" in table #1 to value "otherDescription" from table #2 respectively this id. I wrote the query:

```
UPDATE `table_1` SET description = (SELECT oldDescription FROM table_2 WHERE id = id))
```

How MySql will knows that in expression `WHERE id = id` first id taken from one table, and other id taken from second table? How to write this query correct? I think here must be used AS, but i dont know where

Comment: Read about the [`SELECT` MySQL statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

Comment: You can give tables `ALIAS`es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use table mane  eg :

```
  UPDATE table_1 
  INNER JOIN table_2  ON table_1.id = table_2.id
  SET table_1.description =  table_2.oldDescription
```

or table name alias

```
  UPDATE table_1 a
  INNER JOIN table_2  b  ON a.id = b.id
  SET a.description =  b.oldDescription
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two tables in the UPDATE, and give each an alias. The you identify the columns using alias.columnname:

```
UPDATE `table1` a
JOIN `table1` b ON a.`id` = b.`id`
SET a.description` = b.`otherDescription`
```